# PHP Startup: oci8: Unable to initialize module

Tags: php, oracle, apache, oci8

I've been trying to add the oci8 extension to PHP but when I try to see if everything is ok, running the php command in the console I have this error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: oci8: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20121212
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

Can you help me? I have OSX 10.9.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what I did to solve this problem was compiled oci8 library on my mac in order to have the same number of API:

```
pear download pecl/oci8
tar xvzf oci8-1.4.5.tgz
cd oci8-1.4.5
phpize
./configure --with-oci8=shared,instantclient,/usr/local/lib
make all install
```

I also followed the instructions on this site: [github](https://gist.github.com/gido/5237100)